# How to run CLI Command on the product Save/update in Admin Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

How I can run an indexer command after save or update the product in the admin through any observer or any plugin?

I want to run "bin/magento wyomind:elasticsearchcore:indexer:reindex product" command when product get update/save in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below module to reindex manually from admin :

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-reindex

or programmatically try with below code :

```
protected $_indexerFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
   $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
   $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

// you can call this function to do reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
   $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
   foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $idx = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
   $idx->reindexAll($id); // this reindexes all
   //$idx->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
}
```

**Note : but better idea to try with manually from admin using plugin.. for programmatically - sometimes its taking more times..**

Comment: Dear Anas,

We need to do it automatically

Comment: I want to run "bin/magento wyomind:elasticsearchcore:indexer:reindex product" command when product get update/save in admin.

Comment: try with here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514026/magento-2-how-to-run-cli-command-from-another-cli-command-class

Answer (score 0):

Hint ;) :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Example;

use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;

class Example
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $application = new Cli('Magento CLI');
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'setup:upgrade',
        ]);
        $output = new NullOutput();
        try {
            $application->run($input, $output);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->critical('Setup upgrade failed.', ['exception' => $exception]);
        }
    }
}
```